# Could not load file or assembly IronPython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I having "Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies" problem.

> Could not load file or assembly 'IronPython, Version=2.7.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm installed the IronPython with NuGet package and run the project. Finally, I got this error.

Any ideas how I should go about solving this?

Comment: does it give any inner exceptions, where you able to fix it? I had a similar problem installing the wrong subdependencies and/or having IPY also installed sepperately.